# Get formatted log message

Tags: java, log4j

When you log a message, for example:

```
log.error("This is a message");
```

The message is formatted by the layout before logged in a file. For example:

**2014-12-12 13:45:18 ERROR This is a message**

How can I get this formatted message programmatically?

I'm using JAVA with log4j.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I think one solution is generating a LoggingEvent programmatically and call the format method of my custom Layout, but I think it will not have the same timestamp.

Comment: Do you mean; how do I see what formatting class is used in my logging configuration file? Hint: its the pattern setting.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are using log4j 2 (haven't got the reputation to comment to ask for clarification - the answer would differ a lot for log4j 1.2).  The solution below gives you programmatic access to a String object that contains the exact same string as the message output to the file.

In this case - you can get the actual formatted string as follows:

1. get the MessageFactory : `myFactory = Logger.getMessageFactory();`
2. call `String formattedCopyOfMessage = myFactory.newMessage("This is a message").getFormattedString();`

This is an unusual use case.

Note - the method I suggest ***doesn't*** give you acces to the actual object the logger generates, it is a different String object that will contain the same string of characters.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using version 1.2.

Comment: OK. Can you explain a bit more about your use case?  You could use a WriterAppender instead of a FileAppender - append the message to an OuputStream that you can then programatically access and (optionally) direct to a file if you want.  To do this - you need to have access / be allowed to change the Appender when the logger is set up. If this fits your situation - I'll put details in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not clear. Did you mean how to set the layout of an log4j appender programmatically? If so here's how you would do it

```
  ConsoleAppender console = new ConsoleAppender(); //create appender
  //configure the appender
  String PATTERN = "%d [%p|%c|%C{1}] %m%n";
  console.setLayout(new PatternLayout(PATTERN)); 
  console.setThreshold(Level.FATAL);
  console.activateOptions();
  //add appender to any Logger (here is root)
  Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(console);
```

You can then remove all existing appenders on the root logger with

```
 Logger.getRootLogger().getLoggerRepository().resetConfiguration();
```

Comment: Sorry If my question was not clear. I don't want to set a layout programmatically, I have a custom Layout and I want to get the message that will be outputed to the file when I do a log.error(XXXX). PD: Sorry for my English.